# What does this type of declaration mean?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
graph[100][100],T[100];
```

What does the `T` mean? I was looking up "ways to declare a multidimensional array", but I did not find something syntactically equal.

Comment: It's the name of the variable. The line makes two variables, one is called `graph` and the other one is called `T`. `graph` is a `100x100` 2D array, and `T` is a 1D array.

Comment: Oh! makes sense! Apologies.. I'm new to CPP and thought it would be some kind of declaration.

Comment: You need to spend more time with your text books, as that should have been explained in them.

Comment: The type is missing.

Comment: It is a declaration ... or it would be if there were a type at the beginning. As is, it's just an expression involving array indexing and the comma operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `,` separator is used as a separator in the variable declaration list. This statement declares 2 variables:

- `T[100]`, one dimension statically-allocated array of length 100 labeled `T`.
- `graph[100][100]`, two dimension statically-allocated array of volume 100x100 labeled `graph`.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the `T` mean?

`T` is the name of the variable. The type of the variable is array of 100 objects of some type, which you cut off from the example.

`graph` is another variable, that is an array of 100 arrays of 100 objects of that same type. The variable declarations are separated by a comma. Here is a simpler example using comma to separate variable decarations of same type:

```
int i, j;
```

Answer (score 2):

both graph and T are array
graph is a 2d array staring with graph[0][0] ending to graph [99][99]
while T is a 1d array from T[0] to T[99]
in general array starts from 0 to n-1 for of size n.
But you forgot to mention data type
eg: data_type graph[100][100],T[100];